# How to get multiple columns in a line rapidly when dealing with huge file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a huge file with 5000 column and 1,000,000 row. The columns in a line is separated by `\t`, each cell is string with almost random length. I want to reach specific columns in each row and evaluate them. Usual approaches are too slow. I have written a code like that to fasten the reaching the cells:

```
def amk(theLine, delimiter, columnList):
    ind = -1
    for col in columnList:
        for _ in range(col):
            ind = theLine.find(delimiter, ind + 1)
        yield theLine[ind + 1: theLine.find(delimiter, ind + 1)]

def columnListProcessor(columnList):
    columnList.sort(reverse=False)
    return [columnList[0]] + [columnList[i] - columnList[i - 1] for i in range(1,len(columnList))]

# Let's use a random columns to process for here.
# Amount of column can be more than 500
columnList = columnListProcessor([1, 3, 31, 232, 443, 514, 801, 1032, 1500, 2540, 2983, 3500, 4000, 4441, 4982])

with open("hugeFile.txt", "r") as theFile:
    theLine = theFile.readline()
    while theLine:
        for k in amk(theLine, "\t", columnList):
            if condition:
                foo()
        theLine = theFile.readline()
```

I can say that this is actually rather fast. However, I realized that the function `amk` can be better. When it is yielding the result it executes `theLine.find(delimiter, ind + 1)` so it finds the next `\t`. However, it does not save the next `\t`'s index so for the next time it is called to yield next column in the list, it executes `theLine.find(delimiter, ind + 1)` to find out next `\t` again. I mean it finds out the next `\t` **two times**, which can cause my code to work slower.

I tried to create a new generator for indexing which contains `theLine.find(delimiter, ind + 1)` but it did not fasten the process, though I might have written it not nice. I could not solve this issue, I could not fasten the code although it can clearly work faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 500 columns out of 5000, splitting all of the ones the the delimiter seems more appropriate:

```
def amk(line, delimiter, column_list):
    split_line = line.split(delimiter)
    for col in column_list:
        yield split_line[col]

column_list = [1, 3, 31, 232, 443, 514, 801, 1032, 1500, 2540, 2983, 3500, 4000, 4441, 4982]

with open("hugeFile.txt", "r") as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        for k in amk(line, "\t", column_list):
            print(k)
```

The `.split()` method for strings is implemented in C. Therefore, it is really fast. Even though you might do fewer searches with `.find()`, you need to call this from Python multiple times. In comparison to one call to a function (method) in C, multiple Python function calls are slow. Even though the method `.find()` is itself also implemented in C, you need to call it many times from Python as compared to the number of times you call `.split()`.

In general, you always need to measure run times. Often it is not that obvious what approach is faster for your use case.

Comment: I appreciate your interest and thank you for your answer. I think split method makes the code is way more slower than what I did.

Comment: Try it out and time it.

Comment: Yes, your way looks nearly 3 fold faster than mine. But I cannot understand why. I do not tire processor to split cells of not interest. Would you like to explain why? I thought if I omit splitting unnecessary cells, I could reach cells of interest really fast